# Postgres user can't select from public tables

Tags: postgresql, schema, public, rights

Hello I have one user in my postgresql db
\dt output for the user:

```
 test=> \dt
                  List of relations
 Schema |           Name           | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------------------------+-------+----------
 public | code                     | table | postgres
 public | code_to_indicator        | table | postgres
 public | indicator                | table | postgres
```

As you can see owner of the tables is postgres
But if run \dt command for postgres user it says:

```
postgres=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

How is it possible? Also if I will try to select by postgres user it also will fail:

```
postgres=# select * from indicator;
ERROR:  relation "indicator" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from indicator;
```

Can anyone help with it? Everything was fine till today, something went wrong I even don't know what. PostgreSQL version: 11.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `postgres=#` at the start of the `psql` prompt means you're connected to the `postgres` database, which is created as a placeholder for admin connections, and usually doesn't have anything in it. If you don't specify a database on the command line, `psql` looks for a database with the same name as the user, so the `postgres` user will connect to this by default.

To connect to the `test` database instead, you can either type `\c test` into the `psql` prompt, or launch it using `psql -d test`.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to see tables in `public` or in any schema when the tablename is not qualified depends on the `search_path` setting.

If you haven't modified `search_path` in a permanent way, issue `RESET search_path;` in your session and try again.

How does `search_path` get modified if not directly by you? Playing an SQL file obtained by pg_dump has the effect of removing `public` from the search path, which is pretty much what this question seems to show.

If it's modified permanently through `ALTER USER postgres SET search_path TO ...` or per database or globally, then it needs to be undone by an equivalent ALTER command.

See [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema) or [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for more.